# how to import user defined datatypes in header (.h) files to c#

Tags: c#

iam  new to c# platform. i have an existing project coded in "C". i would like to import the functions in this existing C code to C#.  also there are many user defined datatypes of type struct and enums in header files. i also want to use this datatypes in my new C# project. how can i import the datatypes in .h and also the function in .c files to C#

Comment: do accept answer if you got the info

Answer (score 0):

C# is the OOD compitable lanague its not like c, so can design the classses rather than go for proceudral way.

ITs better you desing the classes in C# and put the mehods and the enums as per the desing.

Like if the one .h = one C# class , this is just an example.

Break out the .h and .c files in the from the classes and put the method according to it.
I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions in your c project but you will need to create c# types that are compatible with the data types from your c project.

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

If you have a lot of stuff you need in your c code.  You could use c++ cli which is directly able to use both the .net framework and c functions it may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to create a C++/CLI project which works as a thin wrapper between your C# project and the C header files etc. You can directly consume these .h files in your C++/CLI project and then you can directly consume the C++/CLI assembly (dll) in your C# project.